Symbolic matrix formula simplification of identity function
I was doing some math with the new Mathematica symbolic matrices and I was trying to get the result to simplify, FullSimplify does not do anything as well as TensorReduce, especially with Symbolic Identity matrices:
Transpose[SymbolicIdentityArray[{n, n}]] - SymbolicIdentityArray[{n, n}] does not result in a zero matrix, which does not make sense.
In addition, this should be simplified ( I have defined the Symbolic matrix B with the dimensions 2x4) Transpose[(MatrixSymbol["B", {2, 4}])].SymbolicIdentityArray[{2,2}].SymbolicIdentityArray[{2, 2}] to just be Transpose[(MatrixSymbol["B", {2, 4}])]. but it returns the whole expression instead.
Am I potentially missing a simplification step?

Maybe you meant SymoblicIdentityArray[{n}] instead of SymoblicIdentityArray[{n,n}] ? Look at Normal@SymbolicIdentityArray[{2, 2}]

Oh yeah, you are right! I did mean SymoblicIdentityArray[{n}]!

First, you may mean SymbolicIdentityArray[{n}] instead of SymbolicIdentityArray[{n,n}]
Transpose[(MatrixSymbol["B", {2, 4}])] . SymbolicIdentityArray[{2}] . 
 SymbolicIdentityArray[{2}] 

(*Transpose[(MatrixSymbol["B", {2, 4}])]*)

Second, from the documentation, to transpose the SymbolicIdentityArray, We need to specify another argument for Transpose, like
Transpose[SymbolicIdentityArray[{n, n}], 2] - SymbolicIdentityArray[{n, n}]
(*SymbolicZerosArray[{n, n, n, n}]*)

Transpose[SymbolicIdentityArray[{n}], 2] - SymbolicIdentityArray[{n}]
(*SymbolicZerosArray[{n, n}]*)


Yes you are right, I did mean SymoblicIdentityArray[{n}] instead! Now it does seem to properly do the simplification. The only problem now is that the result Dot[] when doing Transpose[SymbolicIdentityArray[{n}], 2] .   SymbolicIdentityArray[{n}] .SymbolicIdentityArray[{n}] instead of

@DysonSphere From the codes Transpose[SymbolicIdentityArray[{n}], 2] .    SymbolicIdentityArray[{n}] . SymbolicIdentityArray[{n}] // Trace, we can see that Dot[SymbolicIdentityArray[{n}]] gives Dot[]. Maybe it's a bug?

Your understanding of the new Transpose syntax is wrong. Transpose[arr, k] means the dimensions are cycled k positions. For example, you can check the results of Transpose[ArraySymbol["a", {m, n, p, q}], 1] // TensorDimensions. So, for a matrix, Transpose[mat, 2] will return the matrix itself, e.g. mat = {{a, b}, {c, d}}; Transpose[mat, 2] == mat. See also the documentation of Transpose.

@MichaelChen You are right. So it should be Transpose[SymbolicIdentityArray[{n}], 1] - SymbolicIdentityArray[{n}]
